# Tomcat is starting but can not access to localhost:8080

Tags: linux, tomcat, localhost

I have spent several whole days to start the `tomcat 5.5.36` on my server. I am sure tomcat is starting because I use the command below

```
netstat -anp |grep 8080
```

The result shows the Java is listening on the port 8080.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7615/java
```

After I use the command hostname to get my localhost name and type it in the browser like

```
http://my.domain.com:8080
```

The chrome says the `Error 101` (`net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`): `The connection was reset`.

Anyone can give me some helps. Thanks.

---

**Update**

The log says :

```
Feb 19, 2013 2:10:56 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 19, 2013 2:10:56 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Feb 19, 2013 2:10:56 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/11  config=null
Feb 19, 2013 2:10:56 PM org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
INFO: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
Feb 19, 2013 2:10:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 923 ms
```

---

**Update Feb 20**

My problem gets solved and it is caused by the firewall issue. I try to use another laptop and telnet my server. The server says the connection is refused and I realized the port 8080 is not open to the outside.

Hope it will help others.

Comment: what does the console log say when you start the tomcat server ?

Comment: it would say "INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-<port>

Comment: did you switch to a different port?

Answer (score 1):

> tomcat 5.5.36

You should upgrade.  That is a seriously old version and no longer supported.

> CONNECTION_RESET

Look in server.xml.  Is the HTTP (not HTTPS and not AJP) connector the one listening on port 8080?

In any case, I suggest starting from scratch with the vanilla download of Tomcat7.

Comment: Yes. Http connector is listening on port 8080. What do you mean CONNECTION_REST?

Comment: CONNECTED_RESET is from your Chrome error message.  It typically means the application you're connected to is saying "you're not speaking the protocol I expect, go away."  Again, use an unmodified (and modern) version of Tomcat.